# Strange DateTime format when returned from the Action in JSON type

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

My Action:

```
 public ActionResult Foo()
    {
        var date = DateTime.Now;
        return Json(date);
    }
```

and in the View I use post to visit the Action:

```
   $.post("../../Foo",function(data){
             alert(data);
   })
```

so strange the datetime truned to this format:

```
"/Date(1366340594875)/"
```

Anyone could tell me why? I want the date time what it is like "2013-1-1".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how json dates are formatted by default. You might want to take a look at [How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date)